# How to merge user accounts in different systems?

Tags: c#, microservices

I writing a system that synchronyze with another systems. We work on user account synchronization. Currently I faced with next problem:

User register in System_1 and then register in System_2.

System_2 send notification (via RebbitMQ) to  System_1.

System_1 should understand is it need to create new account OR Update existed account and write a ExternalID for concrete user.

What about best practice of how it should be done?

Comment: The my main problen is: how should be done "merging" mechanizm? Is it exists some good DesignPattern?

Comment: There is no best practice. the best practice is the one that works for you. Suggest you make an attempt, see how far you get then post your code and any problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using token based authentication, you can pass token between your systems.

Comment: I imagine it's AD, not just as simple as a token